# Navigation bar in Communities Designer

Tags: community, customer-community

Using the new Community Design Templates in Winter 15 release is it possible to add links to the navigation bar? I would like to add a custom page to the navigation bar not defined by topics.

Is this possible or is the only navigation option defined by topics when using the Community templates?

Comment: Yes - To my knowledge the templates should not stop you from changing this
Setup -> communities -> All communities -> Action -> Admin Settings -> Tabs and pages.

Then select the tabs and pages you want. 
If they are not displaying check that you have given the correct permissions for the profile.

Comment: @TimChadwick I am using the new community designer templates released in Winter 15 not the tabs functionality. https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/community_templates.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone runs into this working with the new site templates, you can **not** modify the navigation element it only pulls topics mapped to data categories.

What you can do is build your own traditional navigation and use this as more of a breadcrumb style navigation bar.